# Good notation for a function with set of numbers as range

Tags: functions, notation

I am trying to define a function from strings to sets of indices on those strings. Is there a good notation for this?
$f(\Sigma^*)\to\{\mathbb{N}\}$ or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

The standard notation for specifying the domain and codomain of a function $f$ is
$$f: D \to C$$
where $D$ is the domain and $C$ is the codomain. So your example could be written $f: \Sigma^* \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, depending on what you mean by "sets of indices on those strings." Here $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ denotes the power set of the natural numbers, i.e. the set of all subsets of natural numbers.

Comment: Thanks! I think the powerset notation is what I needed. The function selects specific indices of the string.
For example, if the input is ABFABFABFBBAF and the function selects positions 1,5,7 then we would have $f(ABFABFABFBBAF) = \{1,5,7\}$